# GPUImage filtering video

Tags: ios, gpuimage

This is a follow-up to a previous but only marginally related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621025/filtering-video-with-gpuimage)

I'm using the GPUImage library to apply filters to still photos and videos in my camera app. Almost everything is working nicely. One remaining issue that I have not been able to resolve is as follows:

1. I capture a GPUImageMovie
2. I write it to the file system
3. I read it from the file system and apply a new filter
4. I write it to a different URL in the filesystem

What is saved to that new URL is a video with the correct duration but no movement. When I hit play, it's just a still image, I think the first frame of the video. This happens anytime I apply any filter to a video that I retrieve from the filesystem. Applying a filter to live recording video works just fine. My code is below.

Can anyone tell me how I can modify this to save the entire original video with a filter applied?

```
- (void)applyProcessingToVideoAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withFilter:(GPUImageFilter *)selectedFilter
{
    NSArray *urls = [self.videoURLsByIndexPaths objectForKey:self.indexPathForDisplayedImage];
    NSURL *url = [urls lastObject];
    self.editedMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url];
    assert(!!self.editedMovie);
    [self.editedMovie addTarget:selectedFilter]; // apply the user-selected filter to the file
    NSURL *movieURL = [self generatedMovieURL];
    // A different movie writer than the one I was using for live video capture.
    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 640.0)];
    [selectedFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
    movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
    self.editedMovie.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [self.editedMovie enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];
    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [self.editedMovie startProcessing];

    __weak GPUImageMovieWriter *weakWriter = movieWriter;
    __weak CreateContentViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        [selectedFilter removeTarget:weakWriter];
        [weakWriter finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler:^{

            NSArray *urls = [weakSelf.videoURLsByIndexPaths objectForKey:weakSelf.indexPathForDisplayedImage];
            urls = [urls arrayByAddingObject:movieURL];
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableVideoURLs = [weakSelf.videoURLsByIndexPaths mutableCopy];
            [mutableVideoURLs setObject:urls forKey:weakSelf.indexPathForDisplayedImage];
            weakSelf.videoURLsByIndexPaths = mutableVideoURLs;
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.filmRoll reloadData];
                [weakSelf showPlayerLayerForURL:movieURL onTopOfImageView:weakSelf.displayedImageView];
            });
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Well according to this thread https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1321 , it seems there could be an issue on the 'endProcessing' method implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting an 'answer' to this question for future visitors. My code is working now, but the fact is I'm not sure what made the difference. I don't want the above code to be a red herring for anyone. It's possible that the issue was elsewhere in my code base. However, I want to mention the differences between the method posted in the question and the method in my working code.

1. I simplified the structure of the controller so it's only dealing with one media item at a time. No more videoURLsByIndexPath, I just have self.mediaItem. This makes organization much more manageable, obviously. I also have a suspicion that adding an entry for movieURL to that dictionary inside the completion block of the movie writer may have been related to the unexpected results I was seeing.
2. movieWriter is now a strong property instead of an ivar. This *shouldn't* matter AFAIK, because ivars default to strong references. Nevertheless, that's a difference between what's posted here and my working code.
3. Almost certainly unrelated, but I did put an if-else around `self.editedMovie.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter` to check if the count of `[self.mediaItem tracksWithType:AVMediaTypeAudio]` is greater than 0.
4. Since it was no longer necessary to maintain a dictionary of video URLs, I simply call `self.mediaItem = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];`. I do this *outside* of the movie writer's completion block.

I feel that this is not the most valuable of answers, but I hope that the points I've mentioned here prove useful.