# how to add filters on video using GPUImage?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm making an app that needs to add filter on video;

I use `GPUImageMovieWriter` and `GPUImageMovie` to add a filter on an mp4,  that works fine .

but I want to add more than one filter on one video;

I try `GPUImageFilterGroup` but I just don't know how to make it.
I mean like add brightness filter and const filer at the same time, I try to add one filter first and add an other next, but it takes lots of time, my app could not wait for it.

I use this code to add filter:

```
- (void)inputTwoFilters {

/**
 *  配置视频文件的输入输出
 */
NSString *origalVedioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp4"];

NSURL *origalVedioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:origalVedioPath];

GPUImageMovie *movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:origalVedioURL];

NSString *pathToMovie = @"/Users/hanlan/Desktop/t/test14.mp4";

unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);

/**
 *  获取视频的窗口大小
 */
AVAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:origalVedioURL options:nil];
CGSize size      = [[[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];

/**
 *  构造FilterGroup
 */
GPUImageFilterGroup *filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

GPUImageSepiaFilter *sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:sepiaFilter];

GPUImageVignetteFilter *VeFilter = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init];

[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:VeFilter];

[sepiaFilter addTarget:VeFilter];

/**
 *  sepiaFilter << VeFilter
 *  group <<Initial sepiaFilter 开始
 *  group <<Terminal VeFilter   结尾
 */
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sepiaFilter]];
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setTerminalFilter:VeFilter];

[filterGroup forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:size];

/**
 *  准备构建新视频
 */
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] size:size];

[filterGroup addTarget:movieWriter];
[movieFile addTarget:filterGroup];

movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;

[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"finished!!!");
}];
}
```

it crashed with code :

```
2015-08-22 12:30:33.792 ttt[3002:974193] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:] Input buffer must be in an uncompressed format when outputSettings is not nil'
```

orz......

Comment: can you please add that bcos of which reason it's Crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

[BradLarson/GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

To filter live video from an iOS device's camera, you can use code like the following:

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];

// Add the view somewhere so it's visible

[videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
[customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

[Also find answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621025/filtering-video-with-gpuimage)

[More releted to GPUImage Video Filter](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-image-processsing-using-gpuimage-framework)

## Solution 2

## Filters Apply

```
- (void) applyFilterForVideo : (UIButton *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d,%d",intLastSelFilterTag,sender.tag);
    
    // User cannot use Locked Filters
    if (sender.tag < 22) // Apply condition Just for Filters
    {
        NSLog(@"selected Tag - %@ ",[mutArrLockFilter objectAtIndex:sender.tag]);
        if([[mutArrLockFilter objectAtIndex:sender.tag] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [self shouldReturnWithWalsWithTag:sender.tag];
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if (!isToolboxFilter && !isOriginal)
    {
        if (intLastSelFilterTag == sender.tag)
        {
            if(moviePlayer.rate == 0.0)
            {
                if (isAudioSelected)
                {
                    [self playAudio:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self playMovie];
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            intLastSelFilterTag = sender.tag;
            [moviePlayer pause];
        }
    }
    
    movieFile.delegate   = nil;
    movieWriter.delegate = nil;
    
    [self cancelVideoProcessing];
    [movieFile removeAllTargets];
    [filterGroup removeTarget:movieWriter];
    
    [movieWriter cancelRecording];
    
    movieFile   = nil;
    movieWriter = nil;
    
    [Crittercism leaveBreadcrumb:@"filterVideoItem - Filter"];
    
    btnPlayVideo.hidden          = YES;
    btnPlayVideo.tag             = sender.tag;
    btnLastFilterForVideo        = sender;
    
    __weak UIButton *weakbtnPlay = btnPlayVideo;
    
    isImageEdited = YES;
    
    currentFilterIndex = sender.tag;
    
    if (sender.tag == 0)
    {
        [self normalVideoFilter];
        NSLog(@"select normal");
        return;
    }
    
    if (sender.tag < 22)
    {
        isFilterApplied = YES;
        if (isOriginal)
        {
            originalVideoURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalMoviePath];
            unlink([filterMoviePath UTF8String]);
            newFilterVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filterMoviePath];
        }
        else
        {
            originalVideoURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toolMoviePath];
            unlink([finalMoviePath UTF8String]);
            newFilterVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalMoviePath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isToolApplied = YES;
        if (isOriginal)
        {
            originalVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalMoviePath];
            unlink([toolMoviePath UTF8String]);
            newFilterVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toolMoviePath];
        }
        else
        {
            originalVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filterMoviePath];
            unlink([finalMoviePath UTF8String]);
            newFilterVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalMoviePath];
        }
    }
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.05f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        movieFile                   = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:originalVideoURL];
        
        movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
        
        NSLog(@"movieFile is %@",movieFile);
        
        AVAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:originalVideoURL options:nil];
        CGSize size      = [[[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
        NSLog(@"width - %f,%f",size.width,size.height);
        
        @try
        {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
            
            currentFilterIndex = button.tag;
            
            if (sender.tag < 12 && sender.tag != 2)
            {
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];
                [self setFilterOnImage:toolImage fromTool:NO isOriginal:isOriginal];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 12) // Influencia - Highway
            {
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_SOFTELEGANCE;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageSoftEleganceFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 13) // Dark Side
            {
                [filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:0.0];
                [filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:1.0];
                
                if(intLastSelFilterTag != sender.tag)
                {
                    [filterSettingsSlider setValue:0.50];
                }
                
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_SOBELEDGEDETECTION;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 17) // Blue Velvet
            {
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_AMATORKA;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageAmatorkaFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 2) // Lost Memories
            {
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_GRAYSCALE;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 20) // Miss etikate
            {
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_MISSETIKATE;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageMissEtikateFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 14) // Carousel
            {
                [filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:0.0];
                [filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:360.0];
                
                if(intLastSelFilterTag != sender.tag)
                {
                    [filterSettingsSlider setValue:180.0];
                }
                
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_HUE;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageHueFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 16) // Scatter
            {
                if(intLastSelFilterTag != sender.tag)
                {
                    [filterSettingsSlider setValue:0.15];
                }
                
                [filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:0.0];
                [filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:0.3];
                
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_POLKADOT;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImagePolkaDotFilter alloc] init];
                
                if ([filterGroup isKindOfClass:[GPUImagePolkaDotFilter class]])
                {
                    [(GPUImagePolkaDotFilter *)filterGroup setDotScaling:3.0];
                }
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 19) // Comic Strip
            {
                [filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:0.0];
                [filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:1.0];
                
                if(intLastSelFilterTag != sender.tag)
                {
                    [filterSettingsSlider setValue:0.5];
                }
                
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_SKETCH;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 18) // Alien
            {
                filterType  = GPUIMAGE_COLORINVERT;
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 15) // New 11 - Mist and Shadow
            {
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];
                
                GPUImageSepiaFilter *sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:sepiaFilter];
                
                GPUImageVignetteFilter *VeFilter = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:VeFilter];
                
                [sepiaFilter addTarget:VeFilter];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sepiaFilter]];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setTerminalFilter:VeFilter];
            }
            else if(sender.tag == 21) // New 13 - Superstition
            {
                filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];
                
                GPUImageMonochromeFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageMonochromeFilter alloc] init];
                [(GPUImageMonochromeFilter *)filter1 setColor:(GPUVector4){0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.f}];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:filter1];
                
                GPUImageAmatorkaFilter *filter2 = [[GPUImageAmatorkaFilter alloc] init];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:filter2];
                
                GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter3 = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
                [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)filter3 setBrightness:0.3];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:filter3];
                
                [filter2 addTarget:filter1];
                [filter1 addTarget:filter3];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filter2]];
                [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setTerminalFilter:filter3];
            }
            else
            {
                if (sender.tag >= 22 && sender.tag <= 27)
                {
                    filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];
                    [self setFilterOnImage:toolImage
                                  fromTool:YES
                                isOriginal:isOriginal];
                }
            }
            
            NSLog(@"The frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));
            NSLog(@"Aspect Ratio is %f",size.width/size.height);
            
            float aspectRatio = (size.width/size.height);
            
            if (0) // Fill with the screen bounds.
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth);
                
                if (aspectRatio > 1.0)
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width * aspectRatio, imageView.frame.size.height);
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height/aspectRatio);
                }
            }
            
            //imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y, 320, imageView.frame.size.width / aspectRatio);
            
            float countedWidth  = ScreenWidth;
            float countedHeight = 0.0f;
            
            countedHeight = (countedWidth/aspectRatio);
            
            NSLog(@"Counted Width is %f and Height is %f",countedWidth,countedHeight);
            
            movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:newFilterVideoURL
                                                                   size:CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth)];//
            
            
            if ([self.strFilterSelMedia isEqualToString:kVideo] &&
                APP_DELEGATE.isVideoFromPhotoLibrary)
            {
                [filterGroup setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotateRight atIndex:0];
            }
            
            //[movieWriter setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotateRight atIndex:0];
            /* also try this
             processedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[processedImage CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation];
             */
            
            NSLog(@"1 - %s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            
            // Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
            //Pankaj audio support change
            movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
            movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo      = NO;
            movieFile.audioEncodingTarget      = movieWriter;
            
            __weak GPUImageMovieWriter *weakMoviWriter = movieWriter;
            
            //set any resolution you want
            //[filterGroup forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 320.0f)];
            [filterGroup forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth)];
            [movieFile addTarget:filterGroup];
            [filterGroup addTarget:imageView];
            [filterGroup addTarget:movieWriter];
            
            movieFile.runBenchmark      = YES;
            
            [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];
            
            [movieWriter startRecording];
            [movieFile startProcessing];
            
            __weak GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *weakGPUImageFilter = filterGroup;
            //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
            
            isPlayAgain                    = FALSE;
            urlLastToPlay                  = newFilterVideoURL;
            APP_DELEGATE.urlProcessedVideo = newFilterVideoURL;
            
            isPlayAudioInBackground = YES;
            
            __block NSURL *thelastURL             = urlLastToPlay;
            __block AVPlayer *theMoviePlayer      = moviePlayer;
            //__block UIView *theView            = viewContainer;
            __block GPUImageView *theImageView    = imageView;
            __block NSString *typeOfMedia         = self.strFilterSelMedia;
            
            imageView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio;
            
            NSLog(@"ImageView.size is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(imageView.frame.size));
            
            if (isAudioSelected)
            {
                // NOTE : 0.05 delay to remove gap between sound and video.
                
                [self performSelector:@selector(playAudio:)
                           withObject:nil
                           afterDelay:0.05f];
            }
            else
            {
                [self playMovie];
            }
            
            //[viewContainer bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
            
            [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
                
                [weakGPUImageFilter removeTarget:weakMoviWriter];
                [weakMoviWriter finishRecording];
                
                NSLog(@"Finish movieWriterSoftElegance");
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                               ^{
                                   AVURLAsset *asset        = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:thelastURL options:nil];
                                       
                                   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
                                   
                                   float currentDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(theMoviePlayer.currentTime);
                                   
                                   [theMoviePlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

                                   [theMoviePlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
                                   
                                   
                                   //[theView sendSubviewToBack:theImageView];
                                   float timeToDispatch = (CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) - currentDuration);
                                   
                                   if ([typeOfMedia isEqualToString:kVideo])
                                   {
                                       timeToDispatch = 0.0f;
                                   }
                                   
                                   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeToDispatch * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                                      ^{
                                                           [theImageView setHidden:YES];
                                                           [theMoviePlayer pause];
                                                          
                                                           if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
                                                           {
                                                               [audioPlayer stop];
                                                               [timer invalidate];
                                                               timer = nil;
                                                           }
                                                          
                                                           [theMoviePlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero
                                                                    completionHandler:^(BOOL finished)
                                                                          {
                                                                          }];
                                                      });
                                       
                                 });
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
                        weakbtnPlay.hidden = NO;
                    });
                });
            }];
            
            //        isPlayAgain                    = FALSE;
            //        urlLastToPlay                  = newFilterVideoURL;
            //        APP_DELEGATE.urlProcessedVideo = newFilterVideoURL;
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",exception);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thank you for the code, i'm reading it and trying to make it work in my app, i will let you know if it works fine or not. thanks again.

Comment: @罗储华, Ohk Good luck brother

Comment: I try to make it work, but still there are problems........I will post my code in my question, and i found an other problem too....when i use GPUImage to add filter, some times it will drop painting....i wander if there are any simple way to solve it?

Comment: now i solve old problem,but another problem show up now......it shows that :   Input buffer must be in an uncompressed format when outputSettings is not nil'

Comment: @罗储华, if my answer helps you, then please upvote it.